# How I can save logs to file, using npm module "debug"

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, npm

I am using debug module https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug
for logging in my app. How I can save logs to file, using this module???
(I can't change debug module to other, because project is big, and will should refactor much code)

Comment: you can redirect the output to file using >> no code change

Comment: DEBUG=* node dist/index.js>log-file.txt 2>error-file.txt
this fixed my problem, but when I run with pm2 - error-file.txt using pm2 logs, not mine :(